# Performant querying of an ACL against large database datasets

Tags: c#, database, design-patterns, architecture, acl

I am updating a web application which requires more dynamic control of the permissions/access that users have against the domain resources of the application.  These rules also need to be easily configurable by the administrator users of the application.

-

**BACKGROUND:**

My first step was to write an ACL Module - I wanted something simple and something type-safe for this which was surprisingly hard to find, so I ended up writing my own implementation.

The ACL Module provides us now with the following:

- Groups
- Privileges (e.g. View/Add/Edit)
- Resources  (e.g. Product, Page, File etc)
- Rules (i.e. Allow/Deny a Privilege for a Group on a Resource)

An example of their usage:

```
// Setting the ACL rule:
acl.Allow<View>(adminGroup, aProductResource); 

// Asserting the ACL rule:
if (acl.IsAllowed<View>(adminGroup, aProductResource))
{
    // allowed! :)
}
```

The Group structure is represented as a Directed Acyclic Graph (i.e. Multiple inheritance, like a family tree for e.g.), and the rules inherit down the group relationships.  i.e. a child group inherits the ACL rules from the parent group.

Resources themselves can also have rules directly configured for them (for a group, or for all groups), and they also have a relationship to each other, meaning a child resource inherits the rules from the parent.

Pretty standard sort of ACL stuff I think, but fairly complex when asserting access to a resource as you have to first "merge" all the rules from the parent groups/resources based on your context and then calculate the result.

I keep all the rules loaded in memory for performance reasons, and they are serialisable, allowing for quick saving/loading of them.  Mapping the rules to database tables in a normalised fashion seemed nigh impossible.

-

**PROBLEM:**

Asserting the ACL rules against a single domain resource works perfectly, however problems arise when required to parse over large amounts of data.

The application I am updating is "database driven" with fairly large amounts of data in it (i.e. millions of "Resources").

As an illustrative example; there are instances where users need to be able to browse/page through all the "products" that they have "View" access to.  This is problematic for me, as currently to do this there are some stored procedures which do the filtering and returning of the data.  To replace this component with my ACL system I will need to load all the data from the database into the application and then parse over the records using the ACL Module to check if users have access to them.  This is obviously a very intensive task, and one that I am struggling to find a solution for.

One possible solution for this I have thought of is to actually pre-compute and store the results for the ACL asserts for each group against each product.  This could then be stored in a fairly simple schema database table which contains a simple Yes/No result for each possible ACL assertion, making querying fairly straight forward.  I could then do joins on this table to provide massive dataset querying capabilities that still take the ACL rules into account.  There is obviously going to be a fair amount of background work being executed for this solution as every time a "product" is added, or the rules change, this would require re-calculation of possibly most of the entire ruleset.  Another concern is that this table could get pretty huge itself especially as more and more groups/privileges are added to the ACL system.  A record in this table would be required PER group PER resource PER privilege, so I will have to aware of this if I push through with designing it.

-

**QUESTION:**

Is there any known strategy to allow for this type of ACL Module implementation to have performant querying across large data sets from a database?

Perhaps there is an ACL library, for any language, out there that takes large scale ACL querying into account?  Hopefully it's open source too and I can learn from it. :)

I am hoping I am just being completely ignorant to a clever solution to this type of problem. :)

-

This may be a very broad/vague problem description and question.  I apologise if it is so. Please let me know if this is the wrong forum for this type of question, or if you recommend any specific piece of additional detail.